# How to access certain values of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a program which requires the input/output of multiple data types, including a char which stands for the type of sport a patron is making a reservation for, an int which represents their age, and a double that is the output based on the patrons age and sport they want to reserve a spot for, which represents their insurance rate.

So, the logic of the program simplified is Enter program » choose to add a reservation » enter sport using a char » enter age using an int » compute the insurance rate given those circumstances and return it to display to the user.

I will be using arrays for the char, storing the sport they wish to partake in, an array for the age, an index integer which will keep track of which spot in the array that the user is entering the data into, and I might need to make an array for the insurance rate.

Anyways, TL;DR how can I say, access the specific elements of an array to print out something like "a patron the age of `patron_age[index]` reserved a session of `sport_type[index]`" in a function based off of which sport the user is requesting to see information on? I'm really lost.

Here's the code if that helps. It's nowhere close to done yet.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print_menu(); //Prototypes
int input_choice();
void input_reservation(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, double insurance_Rate);
char input_type(char sport_type[], int index);
int input_age(int patron_age[], int index);
double compute_rate(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, double     insurance_Rate);
void print_all(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, int size);
void print_by_sport(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, int size);

int main() //Main Function
{
    int patron_age[100];
    char sport_type[100];
    int index = 0;
    double insurance_Rate;
    int menu_choice; //Variable Declaration
    do
    {
        int size = 0;
        print_menu();
        menu_choice = input_choice();
        if (menu_choice == 1)
        {
            input_reservation(patron_age, sport_type, index, insurance_Rate);
            cout << "Size is equal to " << size << " it will now be incremented" << endl;
            size++;
            index++;
            cout << "Size is now equal to " << size;
        }
        if (menu_choice == 2)
        {
            print_by_sport(patron_age, sport_type, index, size);
        }
        if (menu_choice == 3)
        {
            print_all(patron_age, sport_type, index, size);
        }
        if (menu_choice == 4)
        {
            cout << "The program will now end " << endl;
        }
    } while (menu_choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
void print_menu() //Function that prints the program menu
{
    cout << "Please pick from the following menu " << endl;
    cout << "1. Add a new reservation " << endl;
    cout << "2. Print all reservations " << endl;
    cout << "3. Print all reservations for a given sport " << endl;
    cout << "4. Quit" << endl;
}
int input_choice() //Function to get menuchocie from user
{
    int menu_selection;
    cin >> menu_selection;
    while (menu_selection > 4 || menu_selection < 1) //Validates input
    {
        cout << "\tError: Invalid input, please try again: ";
        cin >> menu_selection;
    }
    return menu_selection; //Returns the menuchocie
}
void input_reservation(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, double insurance_Rate) //Working
{
    double insurance;
    input_type(sport_type, index);
    input_age(patron_age, index);
    insurance = compute_rate(patron_age, sport_type, index, insurance_Rate);
    cout << "The insurance rate is $" << insurance << endl;
} 
char input_type(char sport_type[], int index)
{
    cout << "Please enter f/F for flying, g/G for gliding and h/H for hang-gliding: "; //Working
    cin >> sport_type[index];
    while (sport_type[index] != 'f' && sport_type[index] != 'F' &&     sport_type[index] != 'g' && sport_type[index] != 'G' && sport_type[index] 
    != 'h' && sport_type[index] != 'H')
    {
        cout << "Error: Invalid input, please try again: ";
        cin >> sport_type[index];
    }
    return sport_type[index];
}
int input_age(int patron_age[], int index)
{
    cout << "Please enter the age of the patron, minimum 16: ";
    cin >> patron_age[index];
    while (patron_age[index] < 16 || patron_age[index] > 112)
    {
        cout << "Error: Invalid input, please try again: ";
        cin >> patron_age[index];
    }
    return patron_age[index];
}
double compute_rate(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, double     insurance_Rate)
{
    if (sport_type[index] == 'f' || sport_type[index] == 'F') //If sport index is flying, do this insurance calculation
    {
        if (patron_age[index] <= 25)
        {
            insurance_Rate = 68.95;
        }
        else if (patron_age[index] > 25)
        {
            insurance_Rate = 55.95;
        }
    }
    else if (sport_type[index] == 'g' || sport_type[index] == 'G')//If sport index is gliding, do this insurance calculation
    {
        if (patron_age[index] <= 25)
        {
            insurance_Rate = 73.95;
        }
        else if (patron_age[index] > 25)
        {
            insurance_Rate = 65.95;
        }
    }
    else if (sport_type[index] == 'h' || sport_type[index] == 'H') //If     sport index is hand gliding, do this insurance calculation
    {
        if (patron_age[index] <= 25)
        {
            insurance_Rate = 99.95;
        }
        else if (patron_age[index] > 25)
        {
            insurance_Rate = 92.95;
        }
    }
    return insurance_Rate;
}
void print_all(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, int size)     //Function to print all reservations
{
    cout << "Now printing patron information.... ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    cout << "A patron aged " << patron_age[index] << " reserved a session of " << sport_type[index] << endl;
    }
}
void print_by_sport(int patron_age[], char sport_type[], int index, int size)     //Function to print all reservations based on sport type
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for an assignment, or for fun?  I ask because there may be simpler ways to do this than an array.

Comment: I am downvoting this because the question doesn't include any code showing the problem, among other reasons.

Comment: I'm still willing to help.

Comment: @Brad Thank you, it's an assignment.  Also, I'm not allowed to use structures or classes for the program

Comment: @immibisThe code is in the link to the paste bin. What other reasons?

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting a bit, including for the code.  Follow the pattern for indenting that I used in `main()` to make the code more readable.  That might help remove some of these down votes.  

Now, if I'm understanding correctly, are you looking to print the age of every reservation for a given sport?

Comment: @Brad Yes, so if a user enters the char 'f' for "Flying", all the reservations that fall under that category within the sport_type[index] of char 'f' would be printed out with their corresponding ages. So if a patron age 18 who entered 'f' was in the array, it would print "A patron aged 18 reserved a session of flying"

Comment: @ChrisKeenan The main reason we would like all information pertinent to the question in the question is so that the question can stand the test of time. If the information is stored at another site [it can rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) and this question will be rendered useless to people with the same or similar problems in the future. A common second reason is we don't know what nasty things may be lurking at an off site link and may not be interested in finding out the hard way. One evil flash banner can ruin your whole day,

Comment: Off topic: editing the code I notice many functions claim to return a value (eg: `int input_age(int patron_age[], int index)`) but do not contain a `return` statement. This will lead to no small amount of grief. It is syntactically valid, but is logically undefined and the compiler can do absolutely nothing or generate whatever code it wishes (including seemingly correct code) to do something. Your compiler should be warning you about this.

Comment: Thanks for the edits of the code, @user4581301.  @Chris, it sounds like what you want to do is _search_ the array of sports for all _indices_ that contain a particular value.  In other words, loop through `sport_type` and capture every index that leads to a certain character.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the heads up, I will post the code directly in the future. Should I alter the functions to return instead of setting them equal in the input_new_reservation function? My compiler didn't give me any warnings so I didn't realize this would impact my program operation.

Comment: @Brad So syntatically am I looking at something along the lines of a for loop that goes **(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { if (sport_type[index] == 'insert char here') {print out message} }** with size being a counter variable that I set in main to increment each time a new reservation, and thus an indices of the array is set?

Comment: You have it. Recommend generalizing the function a bit and passing in `'insert char here'` and a string containing a longer description of the sport as parameters. That way you only have to write one function for all sports.

Comment: ...and don't forget to post the final code here so that others can find it in the future.

Comment: Compiler warnings sometimes need to be enabled. In Visual Studio open the properties and navigate Configuration Properties ->C/C++->General and play with the Warning Level. In GCC add a -Wall to the command line or play with the GUI of whatever IDE you're using to set the command line for you. You'll have to look that up yourself because there are dozens of them.

Comment: And part three, in `input_reservation` the line `sport_type[index] = input_type(sport_type, index);` counts on `input_type` returning the correct value, so currently the code blows itself up by not returning. Ideologically, a function should do only one thing, so input should just take input and hand that input off to someone who knows how best to store it. The simpler a function is, the easier it is to debug. So `char input_type(char sport_type[], int index)` should probably be `char input_type()`, read the user input into a temporary value, test the value and return the value when it's good.

Comment: @user4581301 I edited with my current revisions. My program is currently running as far as letting the user enter the desired reservation type and patron age, but is not printing anything when the user enters '2'. I will revise again with the changes you suggested about changing the functions

Comment: The short answer is you have no print statement in the function that handles option 2. You'll learn a lot more figuring out what the print statement has to look like than you will from being fed a canned answer, so I'm going to walk away at this point.

Comment: @user4581301 Alright well thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Also read about how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), aka an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  There seems to be a lot of code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to complete `print_all` and `print_by_sport` function.

You have to assign a unique USER ID for each individual participating in the game else you cannot differentiate two person participating in the same game with the same age.

Since in your program you already defined a variable named `index` that can be used as `USER ID`.

Initially when the program starts to keep the User ID as zero.

IMO, it is better to maintain different array for a different game. Because in your approach when it comes to printing information about a particular sport, it is all scattered in a single array and you gotta loop through entire and check for that particular sport.)

Currently, you have three games defined.

1. flying
2. gliding
3. hang-gliding

Keep three array

```
unsigned int flying_age[100] = {0};
unsigned int gliding_age[100] = {0};
unsigned int hang-gliding_age[100] = {0};
```

When the program starts to initialize `index(USER_ID)` to `0`.

## Algorithm

1. New reservation - Goto Step 4
2. Print all reservation - Goto step 6
3. Print reservation for a particular sport - GOTO Step 7
4. Input game name and age. Based on the game name store the person
   information in that particular array and in that particular `index(USER ID)`.
5. Increment `index(USER ID)`
6. Start for loop(`0 to index(User_id) - 1`) and only one of the array would be set for this particular user id. check it and print
7. Start for loop(`0 to index(User_id) - 1`) and traverse a specific array(one of the above array) and print required information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found it very helpful, but I have since fixed the print_all_reservation function to work properly. However, my problem is actually that the output will currently say something along the lines of "A patron aged 18 reserved a session of g" but what I want it to output in this situation is "A patron aged 18 reserved a session of gliding". Thus, I want to change the char representing the game to the full name of the game. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just before printing below line check for it.

Comment: if (sport_type[index] == 'g')
 cout << "A patron aged " << patron_age[index] << " reserved a session of " << gliding << endl;

or Use enum to get the meaning.